# Chinese typing in mac, keeping the same line spacing as English document

Tags: texshop, cjk

Following instructions from [Chinese typing on mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185817/chinese-typing-on-mac) , I can type Chinese in TexShop, the characters shows properly in PDF file.

What I did is replacing

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
```

with

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[UTF8,nofonts,10pt]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=FandolSong-Bold.otf,ItalicFont=FandolKai-Regular.otf]{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=FandolHei-Bold.otf]{FandolHei-Regular.otf}
\setCJKmonofont{FandolFang-Regular.otf}
```

However, after changing the tex file header, the line spacing becomes bigger.

Before 
[image]

After
[image]

---

Edit according to request from comments:

The part generating the paragraph is like this:

```
 \noindent Let $E/F$ be a field extension, $\alpha \in E$. The {\bf minimal polynomial} of $\alpha$ is the monic polynomial of least degree among all polynomials in $F[x]$ having $\alpha$ as a root; it exists when $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, that is, when $f(\alpha) = 0$ for some non-zero polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$.  最小多项式
```

The whole tex file is as below (I copied the header from somewhere else, not really understand every line)

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[UTF8,nofonts,10pt]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=FandolSong-Bold.otf,ItalicFont=FandolKai-Regular.otf]{FandolSong-Regular.otf}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=FandolHei-Bold.otf]{FandolHei-Regular.otf}
\setCJKmonofont{FandolFang-Regular.otf}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,epsfig,latexsym}
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\def\nr{\par \noindent}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

% This is FULLPAGE.STY by H.Partl, Version 2 as of 15 Dec 1988.
% Document Style Option to fill the paper just like Plain TeX.
\typeout{Style Option FULLPAGE Version 2 as of 15 Dec 1988}

\topmargin 0pt \advance \topmargin by -\headheight \advance
\topmargin by -\headsep

\textheight 8.9in

\oddsidemargin 0pt \evensidemargin \oddsidemargin \marginparwidth
0.5in

\textwidth 6.5in
% For users of A4 paper: The above values are suited for american 8.5x11in
% paper. If your output driver performs a conversion for A4 paper, keep
% those values. If your output driver conforms to the TeX standard (1in/1in),
% then you should add the following commands to center the text on A4 paper:

% \advance\hoffset by -3mm  % A4 is narrower.
% \advance\voffset by  8mm  % A4 is taller.

\begin{document}
 \noindent Let $E/F$ be a field extension, $\alpha \in E$. The {\bf minimal polynomial} of $\alpha$ is the monic polynomial of least degree among all polynomials in $F[x]$ having $\alpha$ as a root; it exists when $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, that is, when $f(\alpha) = 0$ for some non-zero polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$.  最小多项式

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete code, e.g the one which produced the output above?

Comment: Note: I've changed the beginning of your XeLaTeX code. You had put the instruction `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` on the same line as `% !TEX program = XeLaTeX`, which probably made the former comment ineffective.

Comment: Is it a Chinese document or an English document with a few Chinese characters? The `ctex` bundle changes the document layout a lot, including the line spacing. You can use `\linespread{1}` to make the text single spaced.

Comment: @LeoLiu I'm just testing. So do you mean if i) it's a Chinese document, then I can use \linspread{1} to reduce the line spacing? ii) if it's an English document with a few Chinese characters, is there another way, say, avoiding ctex bundle?

Comment: @athos: Exactly. If it is an English document, you can just use `xeCJK` and set the fonts. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17637/2674

Comment: @LeoLiu Great! It works: put "% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode" at the beginning of the document, then "\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STFangsong}
\begin{document}
文章内容"